# How to visualize a sphere bundle?

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, topology, quantum-anomalies, supergravity

In the paper ``[Gravitational Anomaly Cancellation for M Theory Fivebranes](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9803205)", the authors consider removing a tubular region of radius $\epsilon$ around the M5 brane (in order to make sense of the three form near the brane in a limiting sense, after smoothing the source, for purposes of anomaly inflow calculations).

In their notation

$$M_{11}-D_{\epsilon}(W_6)$$

is the 11-manifold with a tubular region of radius $\epsilon$ removed. Further, they also state that the boundary of this punctured 11-manifold is

$$\partial(M_{11}-D_{\epsilon}(W_6)) = -S_\epsilon(W_6)$$

where $S_\epsilon(W_6)$ is the so called **4-sphere bundle over $W_6$**.

Is there a way to visualize this construction?

I am a bit puzzled by this terminology because I think $S_\epsilon(W_6)$ should have dimension 10. In what sense is this a ``sphere bundle''?

Comment: What is wrong with it having 10 dimensions? Remember, this is the boundary of M11.

Comment: I didn't say there's anything wrong with it. I was just looking for a way to visualize it. I think one way is to imagine a ball  attached to each point in $W_6$. The balls are of course in the space transverse to the brane and the "ball bundle" is $D_{\epsilon}(W_6)$.

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with it, what is puzzling you?

Comment: I can see that the boundary of $D_{\epsilon}(W_6)$ should be a 10 dimensional manifold. Further, since the transverse space has 5 dimensions, and $S^4$ is the coset $SO(5)/SO(4)$. So there should be 4-sphere somewhere. What I do not directly see how is this is a ``4-sphere bundle''. Does that adequately address my puzzlement? I should say that I am trying to get more comfortable with this language, and have only fuzzy notions of it. So if you can suggest a more natural transition for a physics student to appreciate it, or maybe some references, it would be nice. Thanks for your help!